# How do I add more than one quality inside a foreach

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
$url = $link->getattribute('href');
$num = $link->nodeValue;   
echo '<source src="'.$url.'" type="video/mp4" label="----quality----" />';
}
```

The video link is repeated 5 times .. I want to add quality to each video [240-360-480-720-1080] .. I searched a lot and did not find a solution to my problem and I hope that there is an example

Comment: Did you try another nested `foreach()` loop? What does the URL look like with the quality included?

Comment: Do you mean the first video should have `quality=240`, second one should be `quality=360` and so on?

Comment: You have to clearify your question, where do you have the quality stored? If it's not stored under what conditions would you declare what quality?

Comment: Yes, every link has quality

Comment: I do not store it, it is displayed in a player

Comment: Please show us an example of the `<a>` tags inside that div. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index in the `foreach` and then use this as the index into an array of qualities.

```
$qualities = [240, 360, 480, 720, 1080];

foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $index => $link) {
    $url = $link->getattribute('href');
    $num = $link->nodeValue;   
    $quality = $qualities[$index];
    echo '<source src="'.$url.'" type="video/mp4" label="----' . $quality . '----" />';
}
```

Comment: @Barmar I don't mean this sentence >> I can't thank you<<< I mean I am grateful to you..but the translation is wrong

Comment: I think what you meant was "I can't thank you enough".

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean